# More pythonic way to write DataFrame to a file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, file-writing

I have a large DataFrame of coordinates, and I have to write its content into an input file for another program. For now I have a nested, quite complex for-loop and many .write() statements - it takes a lot of time to write the file. I can't find nor figure out any smarter way to do it.

#### DataFrame

| type | Uiso | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| H | 0.0320 | 0.257510 | 0.254363 | 0.021930 |
| H | 0.0330 | 0.255228 | 0.163941 | 0.038431 |
| H | 0.0330 | 0.255228 | 0.163941 | 0.038431 |
| C | 0.0278 | 0.122879 | 0.207314 | 0.027545 |
| H | 0.0320 | 0.534974 | 0.254363 | 0.021930 |

#### Input

- First line: atom type.
- Second line: number of these atom types in structure, atom number (H: 1, C: 6, etc.), then occupancy (always 1), then Uiso.
- Rest of the lines: x y z coordinates.

Repeat for each atom type in DataFrame.

```
  H
    4 1  1.000 0.0320
      0.257510  0.254363  0.021930
      0.255228  0.163941  0.038431
      0.255228  0.163941  0.038431
      0.534974  0.254363  0.021930
  C
    1 6  1.000 0.0278
      0.122879  0.207314  0.027545
```

#### Code:

```
f = open(file_name + ".inp", "w")

for type in structure["type"].unique():
    for Uiso in structure[structure["type"] == type]["Uiso"].unique():
        f.write("  " + type + "\n")
        f.write("    " + str(len(list(structure[(structure["type"] == type) & (structure["Uiso"] == Uiso)][["x", "y", "z"]].iterrows()))) + " ")
        f.write(str(atomic_numbers[type]))
        f.write(str("  1.000 "))
        f.write(str(Uiso) + "\n")
        for coord in structure[(structure["type"] == type) & (structure["Uiso"] == Uiso)].itertuples():
            f.write("      "
                 + str(coord.x) + " "
                 + str(coord.y) + " "
                 + str(coord.z) + "\n")
f.close()
```

#### Question

Is there a way to reduce the number of loops? Maybe write whole sorted portions of DataFrame at once?

Comment: Try `for name, group in structure.groupby('type'): print(name, group)` and you'll see that you can loop over your 'types' and get a new dataframe (`group`) just for `name` H, then C, etc. This should help quite a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to approach this, e.g. making a template string then filling it with `format()`, but your case might be compact enough to do it on the fly, so to speak.

For example, this does more or less what you want for a DataFrame `df`:

```py
import numpy as np

with open('data.inp', 'wt') as f:
    for atom, group in df.groupby('type'):
        
        # Write the header info using an f-string.
        f.write(f"{atom}\n  {len(group)} 1  1.000 {group['Uiso'].iloc[0]:.4f}\n")
        
        # Write the data table using savetxt for fixed-width columns.
        data = group.loc[:, ['x', 'y', 'z']]
        np.savetxt(f, data, fmt='%10.6f', newline='\n')
```

This produces:

```
C
  1 1  1.000 0.0278
  0.122879   0.207314   0.027545
H
  4 1  1.000 0.0320
  0.257510   0.254363   0.021930
  0.255228   0.163941   0.038431
  0.255228   0.163941   0.038431
  0.534974   0.254363   0.021930
```

Some notes:

- Always use a context for file reading and writing (the `with` block). It's the safest thing to do.
- I tried using `pd.to_csv()` but I don't think it can do fixed width columns, whereas `np.savetxt()` can.
- I sort of guessed/made up the info on the second line of each record; you might need to change some of that.
- You could change the sort order by throwing `sorted()` around the `groupby` using some appropriate key (e.g. a table to look up atomic number or something).

Comment: Worked perfectly and really speed up the process, thank you!